# Chrome extension: onCommitted fires twice *including check for frameId*

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple page-counter extension. If a page matches a given expression (in this case facebook.com), I want it to increment a counter in an array (I want to be able to count separate tabs separately). I set up an onCommitted event to catch the pages going by.

Other people here have had trouble with onCommitted firing once-per-frame, so I made sure to include the frame check. Actually, it seems like there's *nothing* I can check for to identify which onCommitted event is the important one. I have it printing the details of each request, and *both* requests have identical details, down to the timestamp.

It has something to do with attaching an additional onCommitted listener, since commenting out the other listener will "fix" the problem. But I should be able to attach multiple onCommitted listeners, right?

**background.js**

```
'use strict';

var trackedTabs = {};

//if this line is commented out, the below script runs correctly (increments once). otherwise increments twice
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(details) {console.log("listens to all, details are %o", details);});

var tabFunctions = {
    'onBeforeRequest': function(details) {
        //if a tab appears that matches the expression below, "register" it to trackedTabs
        trackedTabs[details.tabId] = 0;
    },
    'onCommitted': function(details) {
        if(details.frameId == 0) {
            //this happens twice per page if the above listener is attached
            console.log("Incrementing page count from %o", trackedTabs[details.tabId]);
            trackedTabs[details.tabId]++;
            //note that the request that increments from 0 to 1 and the one that increments from 1 to 2 have the same details           
            console.log(details);
        }
    }
};
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(tabFunctions['onBeforeRequest'], {'urls': ["*://facebook.com/", "*://*.facebook.com/*"], 'types': ['main_frame']}, ['blocking', 'requestBody']);
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(tabFunctions['onCommitted'], {'url': [{urlMatches: ".*?facebook.*?"}]});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "__MSG_extension_name__",
    "version": "3.2.0",
    "description": "__MSG_extension_description__",
    "author": "Lucidea",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "notifications",
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "webNavigation",
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

### Edit:

**log output when it's broken**

```
background.js:6 listens to all, details are Object
background.js:6 listens to all, details are Object
background.js:16 Incrementing page count from 0
background.js:19 Object {frameId: 0, processId: 897, tabId: 750, timeStamp: 1470333847318.882, transitionQualifiers: Array[1]…}
background.js:6 listens to all, details are Object
background.js:16 Incrementing page count from 1
background.js:19 Object {frameId: 0, processId: 897, tabId: 750, timeStamp: 1470333847318.882, transitionQualifiers: Array[1]…}
background.js:6 listens to all, details are Object
background.js:6 listens to all, details are Object
```

I've uploaded the extension as a zip file to https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbq6iqcgjojhkmo/oncommitted-runs-twice.zip

My Chrome version is 52.0.2743.82

Comment: I can't reproduce. Maybe you're using an old version of Chrome? Can you upload a zipped extension [somewhere](http://expirebox.com/) to test? Also, you're using a strange matching rule for onCommitted (I'd use `hostEquals: 'www.facebook.com'`)

Comment: Issue was already logged in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=450068